# Adding check boxes to contact form

Tags: forms, 8, emails

I am attempting to make a contact form in Drupal 8 using "Contact forms" included in core.  I'm struggling to figure out how to really customize it, like adding radio buttons or check boxes - does this have to be done through the theme_name.theme file?  If so, can someone give me an example of adding elements to the page? I'm new to Drupal so thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Drupal 8, contact forms are entities listed in admin/structure/contact. Once you created the new contact form, on that page select *Manage fields* in the *Operations* column; it's a drop-down selector, so you will need to select it to see that operation, since the default operation for contact forms you create is *Edit*.

> [image: screenshot]

On the page you will see, you can add new fields.

The tricky part is understanding how to show checkboxes: You need to select the right field type. For example, if you want to show 4 checkboxes, then you select *Text (list)* as field type.

> [image: screenshot]

Enter the 4 values you want to show, and enter 4 as *Allowed number of values*.

> [image: screenshot]

To show it as checkboxes, you go to the *Manage form display* of your contact form (in my case, admin/structure/contact/manage/test/form-display, since *test* is the machine name of the contact form I created). For the field you created, it should show the following.

> [image: screenshot]

Change it to *Check boxes / radio buttons* and save.

> [image: screenshot]

Since the allowed values are 4, the contact form will show checkboxes, not radio buttons.

Comment: You sure are thorough!  Thank you very much for such a detailed answer on such a simple question, it worked perfectly.