# adding drop-down subject (html select) to contact form

Tags: 8, entities, emails

I would like to add a select field like a drop-down in the contact form to let user select the reason why they contact (contact, customer support, etc.)

Based on this (excellent) answer [Adding check boxes to contact form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOppD.png), i’ve managed to create a field with check box :

source : [Adding check boxes to contact form](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/197424/adding-check-boxes-to-contact-form)

How can i do that with a select ?

**Solution :**

You can choose in the "manage form display". The column "widget" allow to choose "Select list" (see screenshot)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question you referenced explicitly changes it *from* Select list (Which is the default for list fields) to checkboxes. All you need to do is skip that last step and keep it on Select List, then you have your Select.

Comment: yes, i wasn’t able to choose when i create the field but i discover that you can switch in the "manage form display". The column "widget" allow to choose "Select list" (see screenshot in my edited question)

Answer (score 3):

There is a select form element that you can add to your buildForm or hook override, depending on how you are building your form:

```
$form['example_select'] = [
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#title' => $this->t('Select element'),
  '#options' => [
    '1' => $this->t('Contact'),
    '2' => $this->t('Other'),
    '3' => $this->t('Customer Support'),
  ],
];
```

This is from the Drupal documentation: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Render!Element!Select.php/class/Select/8.2.x.